# Problems to use the EclairJS Server

Tags: node.js, maven, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-toree

I tried to use EclairJS Server following the instructions available here: https://github.com/EclairJS/eclairjs/tree/master/server

after executing: `mvn package` got the following error:

```
Tests run: 293, Failures: 8, Errors: 9, Skipped: 0

 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 04:51 min
 [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-10T07:13:41+00:00
 [INFO] Final Memory: 31M/373M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project eclairjs-nashorn: There are test failures.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Please refer to /root/eclairjs/server/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] 
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

 Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 26.528 sec - in org.eclairjs.nashorn.ZClusterTest
 Running org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest
 Tests run: 8, Failures: 6, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.821 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest
 countByKey(org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest)  Time elapsed: 0.582 sec  <<< FAILURE!
 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: failure - strings are not equal expected:<{"[pandas":1,"coffee":3]}> but was:<{"[coffee":3,"pandas":1]}>
 at org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest.countByKey(PairRDDTest.java:64)

 cogroup2(org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest)  Time elapsed: 0.73 sec  <<< FAILURE!
 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: failure - strings are not equal expected:<[{"0":"[Apples","1":{"0":["Fruit"],"1":[3],"2":[42],"length":3},"length":2},{"0":"Oranges","1":{"0":["Fruit","Citrus"],"1":[2],"2":[21]],"length":3},"lengt...> but was:<[{"0":"[Oranges","1":{"0":["Fruit","Citrus"],"1":[2],"2":[21],"length":3},"length":2},{"0":"Apples","1":{"0":["Fruit"],"1":[3],"2":[42]],"length":3},"lengt...>
 at org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest.cogroup2(PairRDDTest.java:112)

 cogroup3(org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest)  Time elapsed: 0.405 sec  <<< FAILURE!
 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: failure - strings are not equal expected:<[{"0":"[Apples","1":{"0":["Fruit"],"1":[3],"2":[42],"3":["WA"],"length":4},"length":2},{"0":"Oranges","1":{"0":["Fruit","Citrus"],"1":[2],"2":[21],"3":["FL]"],"length":4},"leng...> but was:<[{"0":"[Oranges","1":{"0":["Fruit","Citrus"],"1":[2],"2":[21],"3":["FL"],"length":4},"length":2},{"0":"Apples","1":{"0":["Fruit"],"1":[3],"2":[42],"3":["WA]"],"length":4},"leng...>
 at org.eclairjs.nashorn.PairRDDTest.cogroup3(PairRDDTest.java:124)
```

ests run: 50, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 94.35 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.eclairjs.nashorn.MlTest
LDAExample(org.eclairjs.nashorn.MlTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from examples/ml/LDA_example.js in /ml/mltest.js at line number 214
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.MlTest.LDAExample(MlTest.java:610)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from examples/ml/LDA_example.js
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.MlTest.LDAExample(MlTest.java:610)

Running org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 6, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.064 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest
WordCount(org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.017 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession in file:/root/eclairjs/server/target/classes/eclairjs/jvm-npm/jvm-npm.js at line number 122
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.WordCount(CoreExamplesTest.java:48)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.WordCount(CoreExamplesTest.java:48)

SparkLR(org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession in file:/root/eclairjs/server/target/classes/eclairjs/jvm-npm/jvm-npm.js at line number 122
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.SparkLR(CoreExamplesTest.java:88)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.SparkLR(CoreExamplesTest.java:88)

SparkPI(org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession in file:/root/eclairjs/server/target/classes/eclairjs/jvm-npm/jvm-npm.js at line number 122
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.SparkPI(CoreExamplesTest.java:76)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.SparkPI(CoreExamplesTest.java:76)

SparkTC(org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession in file:/root/eclairjs/server/target/classes/eclairjs/jvm-npm/jvm-npm.js at line number 122
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.SparkTC(CoreExamplesTest.java:64)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.SparkTC(CoreExamplesTest.java:64)

PageRank(org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession in file:/root/eclairjs/server/target/classes/eclairjs/jvm-npm/jvm-npm.js at line number 122
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.PageRank(CoreExamplesTest.java:100)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.PageRank(CoreExamplesTest.java:100)

LogQuery(org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession in file:/root/eclairjs/server/target/classes/eclairjs/jvm-npm/jvm-npm.js at line number 122
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.LogQuery(CoreExamplesTest.java:115)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: Cannot load script from eclairjs/sql/sparkSession
    at org.eclairjs.nashorn.CoreExamplesTest.LogQuery(CoreExamplesTest.java:115)

Can please anyone help me to get through this error or can share some to use apache spark in my node application
Thankyou

Comment: The error says that you have **failed unit tests**. If you fix broken tests, it will build successfully. If you need to skip tests, add `-DskipTests` to your `mvn` command's argument list

Comment: Yes, I have also tried `mvn package -DskipTests`, then also the build fails, how can i fix broken tests ? @ErnestKiwele

Comment: With `-DskipTests`, it cannot fail *because of unit tests*. You would have to fix the other problem making the build fail (or update the post with the other errors)

Comment: you are giving yourself so much trouble for a project that is clearly not being maintained anymore. https://github.com/EclairJS/eclairjs/issues/27

Comment: I have added some of the errors and cause of failure @ErnestKiwele

Comment: So there is no way I can implement spark using Eclairjs in my node application? @eliasah

Comment: Unless you want to fork and maintain that repo, I don't think it's a good idea.