# Apache spark implementation in Nodejs Application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-toree

I want to implement apache spark in my nodejs application,

I have tried implementing Eclairjs but having some issues implementing it.

Comment: what did you try so far? what is the problem?

Comment: you can refer to this link as I am not able to build the package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747880/problems-to-use-the-eclairjs-server @lev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclairjs appears to be dead

if you want to access spark from node, I would recommend using [livy](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy)
livy is a service that runs a spark session, and exposes a rest api to that session.

there seem to a be node client already: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-livy-client
(I never used the node client, so I can't say if it's any good)

Comment: Livy supports submitting spark jobs from any kind of client, but the job itself still needs to be in one of the supported spark languages (i.e. java, scala, python or R). So as long as you are happy to write, say, python snippets, and use your node app to submit them off to the spark cluster... the node-livy-client package will do this for you.

Comment: but what if we want the results to be returned in a paginated format? what is the solution for that?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to store the results returned by your spark jobs to one of the databases supported by spark - hbase, hive sql